# Javascript parseFloat result

Tags: javascript

Consider this script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(parseFloat(parseFloat("97.74")+parseFloat("1.82")) + "<br />");
</script>
```

Why is the result 99.55999999999999 ?
And how can I get the expected output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to floating point numbers :)

You can use [`.toFixed(numOfDecimalPlaces)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) for this, for example:

```
document.write((parseFloat("97.74")+parseFloat("1.82")).toFixed(2) + "<br />");
```

The output of [`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) is a **string**, rounded to the specified number of decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

It's a rounding error, due to the computer working in base 2 whilst your brain works in base 10.

Try this:

```
var x = parseFloat(parseFloat("97.74")+parseFloat("1.82");
document.write(Math.round(x * 100) / 100);
```